# AWS SNS - Do disabled EndpointARNs get deleted automatically

Tags: amazon-sns

I am wondering if the disabled EndpointARNs (Enabled:false) do get deleted automatically by AWS SNS or do they need to be deleted by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon SNS service does not delete disabled endpoints automatically.

You can update a disabled endpoint with a valid token ( ***i.e*** using **REST API** [SetEndpointAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetEndpointAttributes.html) or **CLI** command [set-endpoint-attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-endpoint-attributes.html) ) and enable it or you can create a new endpoint with a valid token and delete the old one ( *i.e using either **REST API** [DeleteEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_DeleteEndpoint.html) or **CLI** command [delete-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/delete-endpoint.html)* )